# calculation of rotated matrix of an Image without the background values in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, background, rotation

I want to make calculations rotating the image per 10 degrees, a big problem occurs.

### Example

Let us rotate a specific image which i call [Images](https://www.sendspace.com/file/15egaj) with the following code:

`imRot = imrotate(Images,20);
 figure,imshow(Images) 
 figure,imshow(imRot)`

As you can see when we rotate Images 20 degrees, values of background appear in imRot matrix which we do not want in our calculations. How can we have Images matrix rotated 20 degrees without backround values in matrix?

Comment: One way would be to choose background values that don't affect your calculations, for example if you're just summing, then `0` is a good choice. Another way would be to clip the corners off your image. It would help if you explain what you want to do next

Comment: @Dan : for each degree (0,10,20,...,330,340,350) make that rotation on image. For all pixels(Images(i,j)),for every degree and for each line every time,sum all pixel values for every line of Images matrix starting from Images(i,j) up to the right last pixel of the line that is Not background pixel value. 

Above you can see 3 examples for imRot = imrotate(Images,20); of what i want:


1. i=84  j=108
Line(i,j,degree)=[imRot(i,j) : imRot(415,108)];

2. i=182  j=108
Line(i,j,degree)=[imRot(i,j) : imRot(415,108)];

3. i=286  j=55
Line(i,j,degree)=[imRot(i,j) : imRot(395,55)];

Comment: @Dan NOT calculating those like :

i=83 j=108 Line(i,j,degree)=[imRot(i,j) : imRot(415,108)]; OR Like: i=286 j=55 Line(i,j,degree)=[imRot(229,55) : imRot(395,55)];

Comment: Ioannis - if you are just summing per row, then make the background values `0` (which I'm sure is what `imrotate` does by default) and they will not affect your calculations.